# Stuck with this

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program that will add together a series of numbers that the user inputs until the user types 0 which will then display the total of all the inputted numbers. this is what i have got and im struggling to fix it

```
print ("Keep inputting numbers above 0 and each one will be added together consecutively. enter a and the total will be displayed on the screen. have fun")

number = input("Input a number")

sum1 = 0

while number >= 1:

    sum1 = sum1 + number

if number <= 0:
    print (sum1)
```

Comment: You haven't explained what's broken.

Comment: Please explain what is wrong. What output are you expecting? What actually output/error are you getting?

Comment: Please explain the problem. What is happening? What is not working? What have you tried to do? The question should have a clear explanation of the problem. But as to the actual issue, read your code through and think on every line what happens, when the user is asked for something etc. You should see the problem. Or get a debugger and run it line by line.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python/NEA practice/sum.py", line 7, in <module>
    while number >= 1:
TypeError: unorderable types: str() >= int()
>>> 
 is the output im getting

Comment: i have managed to fix it now thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more robust way to input the number. It check if it can be added. Moreover I added the positive and negative number.

```
# -*-coding:Utf-8 -*

print ("Keep inputting numbers different than 0 and each one will be added together consecutively.") 
print ("Enter a and the total will be displayed on the screen. Have fun.")

sum = 0
x = ""

while type(x) == str:
        try:
                x = int(input("Value : "))
                if x == 0:
                        break
                sum += x
                x = ""
        except:
                x = ""
                print ("Please enter a number !")

print ("Result : ", sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python 3, you will need to say `number = int(input("Input a number"))` since `input` returns a string. If you're using Python 2, `input` will work for numbers but has other problems, and the best practice is to say `int(raw_input(...))`. See [How can I read inputs as integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers) for details.

Since you want the user to repeatedly enter a number, you also need an `input` inside the `while` loop. Right now it only runs once.